# Calling rest uri in javascript using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am able to call the rest service uri on the server side button click event of a aspx button.

private void Insert(InsertEmployee obj)
    {
    try
    {
    uri = "http://localhost:3324/Issues.svc/ADD/";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpClient().Post(uri, HttpContentExtensions.CreateDataContract(obj)))
    {

```
  int iStatus = response.Content.ReadAsDataContract<int>();
  if (iStatus > 0)
  lblErr.Text = "Record Inserted";
  else
  lblErr.Text = "Insertion Failed";

}
}
catch (Exception)
{

throw;
}
}
```

The above is the method I call to insert records which is working.

Can u help me how to call this method in ajax.I tried the below code but not working.Even if I run this link in browser http://localhost:3324/Issues.svc/ADD/ this is not working says method not found.

function CreateEmployee() {
    alert("S");
    var strService = "http://localhost:3324/Issues.svc/ADD/";
    $.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url": strService,
    "dataType": 'jsonp',
    "data": {"code":"101","empname":"Test140","mode":"I"},
    success: function(json) {
      alert(json);
      //result = jQuery.parseJSON( json );
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    }
    );
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WCF - REST service , do look into this [msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx)